# I'm facing an error while trying to compile the code. Where am I going wrong and How do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

I'm getting the an error on terminal while trying to compile the code, but I don't understand why.

Code:

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

console.dir(app);
```

Error:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mncsl.png]

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "firstapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "npm": "^8.15.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first, check that express is installed or not

if not run the following command

```
npm i express
```

also, check that you are using the latest version of the node

if all ok then run

```
node index.js
```

is still an issue not fixed submit your folder structure and package.json
so I can give you further assistance

Remove npm from dependency

Comment: I tried updating express and node, but even then I'm facing this issue.

I've added my package.json to the question now and my working directory is
/Users/vish1504/documents/node/express/firstapp

Comment: Remove npm from dependency b this will help